# cat is not writing to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, cat

i want to write to a file by cat command.

```
cat $variable >t.h
```

while it is not writing to the file.
The file is empty anyway.
why is cat not writing to the file?

Comment: Does you see the output if you leave out the `>t.h`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cat` itself does not write to file, only to stdout. The shell redirect `>` does the writing.

The problem with your statement is that `cat` takes list of file names as parameter, so `cat $variable` will attempt to print the contents of a file whose name is stored in `$variable` which most likely doesn't exist.

To write the contents of the variable to a file, use `echo $variable >t.h`

Comment: although echo is working could you please elaborate why cat doesnt work while echo works

Comment: @user1065734 cat reads files or stdin. If you provide an argument, it assumes that argument is a filename, which it tries to read. This is not what you want. You are simply trying to print the contents of a variable to a file. There is a "hackish" way to do it using `cat`, but the OP gives the correct answer. `cat <<<$variable >t.h`